# "error": "unauthorized_client", "error_description": "AADSTS700016 (Microsoft Graph API)

Tags: api, python-requests, microsoft-graph-api

I want to access my todo list using Microsoft graph API and so registered an app and after doing the required steps got the access token, but after trying to get the new access token using the refresh token it returns this message: `"error": "unauthorized_client", "error_description": "AADSTS700016: Application with identifier 'id' was not found in the directory 'Microsoft Accounts'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant`

```
class Refresh:

def __init__(self):
    self.refresh_token = refresh_token
    self.scope = scope
    self.client_secret = client_secret

def refresh(self):

    query = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token"

    response = requests.post(query,
                             data={"client_id" : client_id,
                                   "scope": 'Tasks.Read%20Tasks.Read.Shared%20Tasks.ReadWrite%20Tasks.ReadWrite.Shared%20offline_access',
                                   "refresh_token": refresh_token,
                                   "redirect_uri": 'https://github.com/Rohith-JN',
                                   "grant_type": "refresh_token",
                                   "client_secret": client_secret
                                   },
                             headers={"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})

    response_json = response.json()
    print(response)
    print(response_json)

a = Refresh()
a.refresh()
```

I am also not sure if I am entering the scopes in the right way. Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out by changing the URL that refreshes the token from

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token` to this `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token`